# Proving if $a_{k}\ge a_{k-1}+1$ then $1+\frac{1}{a_{0}}(1+\frac{1}{a_{1}-a_{0}})...(1+\frac{1}{a_{n}-a_{0}})\le \prod_{k=0}^{n}(1+\frac{1}{a_{k}})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, products

I've worked on this problem with the sequence $a_{k}$ being the natural numbers, that is $a_{k}=a_{k-1}+1$ and $a_{0}=1$. Over the naturals, $\prod_{k=0}^{n}(1+\frac{1}{a_{k}})$ can be proven to be $n+1$.

I've been able to recognize the obvious pattern in $\prod_{k=2}^{n}(1+\frac{1}{k-1})$ to be equal to $n$, but I do not know how to prove this rigorously.

That said, over the naturals, the inequality reduces to $n+1 \le n+1$. That got me thinking if the sequence in question could be expanded with the condition $a_{k}\ge a_{k-1}+1$ and specifically if this would not lead to the situation corresponding with RHS being greater than LHS.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Big hint: Induction

Comment: Can you check your inequality? In particular, do you want to start with $ ( 1 + 1 / a_0)$? Also, can you write out the $ n = 1$ case, since the LHS seems to be larger to me (because the denominators are smaller), namely $ ( 1 + 1 / ( a_i - a_o )  ) > ( 1 + 1/a_i) $

Comment: The beginning of the inequality is supposed to be the way it is, i.e. no $(1+\frac{1}{a_{0}})$ term. If the term were there then the $n=1$ case would break the inequality indeed. We however have the initial 1.

Comment: Yes, I have tried working with induction but without much success. Could you perhaps sketch it out a little bit more?

Comment: @mivino Induction works pretty directly, so I encourage you to sketch it out a little and explain where you're stuck and why.

Comment: Just an idea putting $v_0=a_0$ and $v_k=a_k-a_{k-1}$ the case $n=2$ seems to be non trivial see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+1%2B%281%2Bb%29%281%2Bb%2Bc%29%2F%28%28a%29%28b%29%28b%2Bc%29%29-%281%2Ba%29%281%2Bb%2Ba%29%281%2Ba%2Bb%2Bc%29%2F%28a%28b%2Ba%29%28a%2Bb%2Bc%29%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given reals $a_0 > 0$ and $ a_k \geq a_{k-1} + 1$, show that $$ 1 + \frac{1}{a_0}\prod_{i=1}^{n}  ( 1 + \frac{1}{ a_i - a_0 })  \leq   \prod_{i=0}^n ( 1 + \frac{1}{a_i}).$$

---

**Claim 1:** $ \prod_{i=0}^n (1 + \frac{1}{a_i}) \leq \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_0} $

Proof: This follows from the telescoping inequalities

$$ \prod_{i=0}^n (1 + \frac{1}{a_i}) =  \prod_{i=0}^n \frac{a_i + 1}{a_i} \leq \prod_{i=0}^n \frac{ a_{i + 1} } { a_i} =  \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_0}. $$

Equality holds iff $a_i = i+a_0$.

**Claim 2:** $ 1 + \frac{1}{a_0} \prod_{i=1}^{n}  ( 1 + \frac{1}{ a_i - a_0 })  \leq \prod_{i=0}^n ( 1 + \frac{1}{a_i}).$

Proof by induction.
Base Case: $ 1 + \frac{1}{a_0} + \frac{1}{ a_0 (a_1 - a_0) } 
\leq 1 + \frac{1}{a_0} + \frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{ a_0 a_1 } \\
\Leftrightarrow  a_1 \leq (a_0+1) (a_1 - a_0) \\
\Leftrightarrow a_0 ( a_1 - a_0 - 1) \geq 0 ,  $
which is true.

Induction step: Applying the induction hypothesis, we have

$$ 1 + \frac{1}{a_0} \prod_{i=1}^{k+1}  ( 1 + \frac{1}{ a_i - a_0 }) \leq 1 + ( 1 + \frac{1}{a_{k+1} - a_0 } ) \times \left[  \prod_{i=0}^k (1 + \frac{1}{a_i} ) - 1 \right] \\
  = ( 1 + \frac{1}{a_{k+1} - a_0 } ) \times \left[  \prod_{i=0}^k (1 + \frac{1}{a_i} ) \right] - \frac{1}{a_{k+1} - a_0} $$

We WTS that the RHS is $\leq ( 1 + \frac{1}{ a_{k+1} }) \prod_{i=0}^{k} ( 1 + \frac{1}{a_i}).$
Shifting terms around and factoring, this is equivalent to showing that

$$ \frac{a_0}{ (a_{k+1} - a_0 ) ( a_{k+1} ) } \times \left[ \prod_{i=0}^k ( 1 + \frac{1}{a_i})\right] \leq \frac{1}{ a_{k+1} - a_0 } .$$

This follows directly from the previous claim by replacing the term in the square brackets.
Again, equality holds iff $a_i = i+a_0$.

---

Note:

- The standard algebraic manipulations of the induction approach yielded the first claim directly. Assuming that this could be proved by induction in a direct manner, the first claim had to be true.
- The first claim could be strengthened to $ \prod_{i=0}^n (1 + \frac{1}{a_i}) \leq \frac{ a_{n} + 1 }{a_0}$.